# Trying to print keys based on their value type (int or str) from a dictionary of lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary, types, boolean

I'm learning to access dictionary keys-values and work with list comprehensions. My assignment asks me to:

```
"Use a while loop that prints only variant names located in chromosomes that do not have numbers (e.g., X)."
```

And I'm working with this dictionary of lists, where the keys are variant names, and the zeroth elements in the list values (the character sets on the left of the colon([0])) are chromosome names, while the characters to the right of the colon ([1])are their chromosome location, and the [2] values are gene names.

```
cancer_variations={"rs13283416": ["9:116539328-116539328+","ASTN2"],\
"rs17610181":["17:61590592-61590592+","NACA2"],\
"rs1569113445":["X:12906527-12906527+","TLR8TLR8-AS1"],\
"rs143083812":["7:129203569-129203569+","SMO"],\
"rs5009270":["7:112519123-112519123+","IFRD1"],\
"rs12901372":["15:67078168-67078168+","SMAD3"],\
"rs4765540":["12:124315096-124315096+","FAM101A"],\
"rs3815148":["CHR_HG2266_PATCH:107297975-107297975+","COG5"],\
"rs12982744":["19:2177194-2177194+","DOT1L"],\
"rs11842874":["13:113040195-113040195+","MCF2L"]}
```

I have found how to print the variant names based on the length of the zeroth element in the lists (the chromosome names):

```
for rs, info in cancer_variations.items():
    tmp_info=info[0].split(":")
    if (len(tmp_info[0])>3):
        print(rs)
```

But I'm having trouble printing the key values, the variant names, based on the **TYPE** of the chromosome name, the zeroth element in the list values. To that end, I've devised this code, but I'm not sure how to phrase the Boolean values to print only if the chromosome name is one particular type, (Str) or (int).

```
for rs, info in cancer_variations.items():
    tmp_info=info[0].split(":")
    if tmp_info[0] = type.str
        print(rs)
```

I am not sure exactly what I'm not seeing here with my syntax.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: ...too much bio-stuffs for me:). So dictionary = {chromosome: [location, gene_name], ...} that's right? could you be more precise about the matching criteria?

Comment: no worries, I understand. It's dictionary = {variant name: [chromosome name: location, gene_name}. The matching criteria is basically I'm just trying to print that one chromosome with the name "X" based on the data type of the chromosome name, its the only one with a name that doesn't feature numbers, so  I figured just isolate it by type str.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you right, you want to check if the first part before `:` contains a number or not.

You can iterate the string *character-by-character* and use `str.isnumeric()` to check if the character is number or not. If `any` character is a number, continue to next item:

```py
cancer_variations = {
    "rs13283416": ["9:116539328-116539328+", "ASTN2"],
    "rs17610181": ["17:61590592-61590592+", "NACA2"],
    "rs1569113445": ["X:12906527-12906527+", "TLR8TLR8-AS1"],
    "rs143083812": ["7:129203569-129203569+", "SMO"],
    "rs5009270": ["7:112519123-112519123+", "IFRD1"],
    "rs12901372": ["15:67078168-67078168+", "SMAD3"],
    "rs4765540": ["12:124315096-124315096+", "FAM101A"],
    "rs3815148": ["CHR_HG2266_PATCH:107297975-107297975+", "COG5"],
    "rs12982744": ["19:2177194-2177194+", "DOT1L"],
    "rs11842874": ["13:113040195-113040195+", "MCF2L"],
}

for k, (v, *_) in cancer_variations.items():
    if not any(ch.isnumeric() for ch in v.split(":")[0]):
        print(k)
```

Prints:

```
rs1569113445
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to look up how to determine your desired classification of the data.  In this case, all you need is to differentiate alphabetic data from numeric:

```
if tmp_info[0].isalpha():
    print(rs)
```

Should get you on your way.

Comment: Thanks for this insight. That method is perfect for this as well. For some reason, when I execute it, it doesn't return any output. I will try and figure it out, but thank you again. Still getting acquainted with useful methods, etc.

Comment: Check the `isdigit` and `isalpha` methods; you can check entire strings for a single isntance if you apply `any` or `all` as well.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to make sure what you want to do.

If what you want is to distinguish a `numeric string` from a normal `string`, then you may want to know that a numeric string is strictly formed of numbers; if you add any other character, it's not considered numeric by python. You can prove this making this experiment:

```
print('23123'.isnumeric())
print('2312ds3'.isnumeric())
```

Results in:

```
True
False
```

Numeric strings is what you are looking to exclude, and any other, in this case, that stays as str, will fit, if i'm understanding.

So, in that manner, we are going to iterate over the dict, using the loop you've made:

```
for rs, info in cancer_variations.items():
    tmp_info=info[0].split(":")
    if not tmp_info[0].isnumeric():
        print(rs)
```

Which results in:

```
rs1569113445
rs3815148
```